# Differences between different getdir() function in android

Tags: android, storage, getdirectories

What are the difference between these kinds of getdir() functions?
I search through Internet, but seems all of them have same function. Then what are the use of them?

```
getExternalFilesDir()
getExternalFilesDirs()
getExternalCacheDir()
getExternalCacheDirs()
getExternalStorageDirectory()
getExternalStoragePublicDirectory()
getFilesDir()
```

Comment: You should have checked the documentation before asking here, just like Vivid did to answer your question.

Comment: I am sorry for that, will delete the post if request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[getExternalFilesDir(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)**

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place persistent files it owns.

**[getExternalFilesDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalFilesDirs%28java.lang.String%29)**

Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all shared/external storage devices where the application can place persistent files it owns.

**[getExternalCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir%28%29)**

Returns absolute path to application-specific directory on the primary shared/external storage device where the application can place cache files it owns.

**[getExternalCacheDirs()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDirs%28%29)**

Returns absolute paths to application-specific directories on all shared/external storage devices where the application can place cache files it owns.

**[getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29)**

Return the primary shared/external storage directory.

**[getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(String type)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStoragePublicDirectory%28java.lang.String%29)**

Get a top-level shared/external storage directory for placing files of a particular type.

**[getFilesDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29)**

Returns the absolute path to the directory on the filesystem where files created with [openFileOutput(String, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#openFileOutput%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) are stored.

these documentations will help you